# hp pavillion dv6 on win8 stuck in black screen while installing 14.04 ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

Hp pavilion dv6 on win8 
I was installing Ubuntu 14.04 using my external hard disk as a USB flash drive. My CPU is a 32 bit laptop. Its not progressing past a black screen with cursor on left top.